# Characters sometimes are deformed

Tags: unity, 16.04

Sometimes I find that characters of my desktop or unity panel are deformed as shown in the next picture. Folders and files names, menus text are hidden.

[image]

I've tried to replace unity or compiz, but no way. I have to reboot the system to get it back.